# Can I use the Khalim's Will flail after completing the Khalim's Will quest?

Tags: diablo-ii

[The Khalim's Will flail](http://diablo.wikia.com/wiki/Khalim%27s_Will_(item)) is a quest item in Diablo II. Crafting it is the main task in Act III. Once crafted, it is used to smash the Compelling Orb and gain access to the Durance of Hate. When you smash the Compelling Orb, you complete the [Khalim's Will quest](http://diablo.wikia.com/wiki/Khalim%27s_Will_(Quest)), and the flail disappears.

Not only does the flail used to smash the orb disappear, but any party members who have the quest completed when the orb is smashed will have their flails disappear as well.

However, the flail is a pretty good weapon. It's better than the weapon my Paladin was using when we defeated the Council. Here are the stats:

> Khalim's Will
> One-Hand Damage: 1 to 15
> Durability: 30 of 30
> Mace Class - Very Fast Attack Speed
> +50% Increased Attack Speed
> +40 to Attack Rating
> Adds 1-40 lightning damage
> 6% Mana stolen per hit
> 6% Life stolen per hit
> +50% Damage to Undead

Is there any way to keep the weapon and continue using it?

Answer (score 9):

Yes, but not with the character that completed the quest.

---

The following is based on in-game experience and direct testing:

Prior to smashing the Compelling orb, you can transfer one or more flails to other characters (i.e. 'mule' them). After the mule has left the game with the extra flails, smash the orb with one of the flails remaining in the game. Once the orb is smashed, all party members will complete the quest.

The flails that were muled away will not disappear, and can be given to other characters who have not yet completed the Khalim's Will quest. Since the flail has no requirements whatsoever - level, strength, or otherwise - it makes an amazing weapon for level one characters.

Or, you can use one of these completed flails to skip the tedious part of Act III. You can go directly to Travincal, kill the council, and use a flail completed in another game to smash the orb. You will, of course, lose the flail.

But, a character who has completed the Khalim's Will quest in a particular difficulty level will be unable to pick up a Khalim's Will flail in that same difficulty level. Attempting to do so will result in the character saying things like "I can't do that" and "Impossible".